# Why do we qualify "dish washer" or "car wash" but not "clothes washer"?

Tags: american-english, general-vs-specific

In theory, any mechanical device that is used to wash another object could be called a "washing machine". However, the term (at least in the US) is almost exclusively used for machines that wash clothes.

Machines that was dishes and silverware are "dish washers". A Machine that washes automobiles is a "car wash". But a machine that washes clothes is just a "washing machine".

How did that generic term come to be so completely identified with a specific type of washing machine?

Comment: When I was a kid, "clothes washer" was a fairly common term.

Comment: *But a machine that washes clothes is just a "washing machine".* This is a false premise. There have been several words for washing machine - "a washer" springs to mind. The commonest use of a noun usually becomes the default and loses its attributive adjective first: in terms of riding, saddle = horse saddle. If you want an elephant saddle or an ostrich saddle, you have to specify from the default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose because it was the first one.

We, in the UK, had washing machines (for clothes) long before dishwashers and car-washers. So that by the time those machines came along, the term 'washing machine' had already been claimed.

It is also the case (at least in Britain) that washing clothes has always been known as 'washing'. A question like: 'When do you do your washing?' almost certainly refers to washing clothes, not to washing dishes etc (that's called 'washing-up') nor the washing of oneself, or the baby (that's bathing, or showering).

Comment: This sounds reasonable, though I'll note that in US usage, washing clothes is not usually called *washing* but more typically *doing laundry* or just *laundry*. If some asked me if I had done my washing I'm not sure what I would assume they meant, but probably bathing/showering barring any context...

Comment: 'Laundry' is obviously used in Britain too, but mostly it is associated with commercial laundries, or launderettes. People are not as inclined to refer to their domestic washing as 'laundry'. At least that's my impression. There are many terms, long since unfashionable in our 'correct' age, associated with 'washing', such as 'wash-day', 'washer-woman' etc. But they all point to a tradition of 'washing' meaning the washing of clothes and bed-linen.

Comment: Your first-paragraph supposition might or might not be correct; IMO, giving opinions rather than facts, when facts can be had, isn't worthy of upvotes.

Comment: @jwpat7 Well at least I follow an honourable tradition, adopted by, among others, the OED, that if I am not completely certain of something I hedge it about with qualifications. Often the OED will say something like: the origin is uncertain but it has been attributed by some to.... Nothing makes me more sceptical than people who know the 'correct' answer. I hesitate to upvote those ones.

Comment: In the US, *washer* may be a more common term for a clothes-washing-machine than is *washing machine*. Perhaps see book links at [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=washing+machine%2Cwasher%2Cclothes+washer%2Cwasher+dryer&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwashing%20machine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwasher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclothes%20washer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwasher%20dryer%3B%2Cc0) for *washing machine,washer,clothes washer,washer dryer*

Comment: @jwpat7 But a 'washer' is what goes between a nut and a screw.

Comment: @jwpat7 I'm not an ngrams expert by any means but wouldn't ngrams pick up "dish washer" as an example of "washer" as well?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield, yes.  That's why I said “see book links”; by looking at numerous instances in books of *washing machine* and *washer* one can estimate how many of each refer to a clothes-washing-machine.  The ngrams numbers per se are not of much use for this question.

Comment: @jwpat7 Presumably it would also get bogged down in nuts and bolts.

Comment: I'd check your dates. "first dishwasher" vs "first washing machine".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well there may have been some sort of commercial dishwasher around  a long time ago. But I wouldn't mind betting that your mother had a washing machine long before (like 20 years before) she had a dishwasher.

Comment: 'We in the UK had washing machines (for clothes) long before dishwashers were in common use here.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That is the point I was making in my answer. I will edit it to make it clear I was talking about the UK. Though the first place we had a dishwasher was when we lived in France in 1976/7.  Few people in the UK had them at that time.

Comment: That is the point you were trying to make in your answer.